# Methods to optimize hyperparameters of an ARD kernel for Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, optimization, gaussian-process, hyperparameter

I am using Gaussian Process regression to build a model from my feature set, which consists of 40 parameters and ~250 samples in my training set. I've chosen an RBF kernel with ARD (different length scales for each parameter). I know that we can derive a point estimate for the hyperparameter values with a point estimate by maximizing the log marginal likelihood as:
$$log(y|X,\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}y^{T}K^{-1}y-\frac{1}{2}log(det(K))-\frac{n}{2}log(2\pi)$$
where y is the set of target outputs, K is the chosen kernel, $\theta$ is the hyper parameter set and N is the number of points.
However, I know that we would need to look for a global optimum - for this large a number of dimensions, I suspect that quasi-Newton methods such as L-BFGS-B would only lead me to a local maximum of this function. I am looking for a way to optimize this function globally instead. I attempted to use simulated annealing (with a high initial temperature and slow cooling schedule) which initiates a search in a broad region, and narrows it down over successive iterations; however, this also does not guarantee a global maximum. As such, I'm looking for potentially other ways (apart from maximizing the marginal log-likelihood function) that is suited for cases with a large number of hyper-parameters. Any inputs/pointers on some techniques that could be used for this would be appreciated.

Comment: GPR optimisation is pretty low-number of hyper-parameters situation... A couple of length-scales and their respective function variances, a noise variance and that's about it. 40 parameters our of 250 samples seems quite excessive,

Comment: @usεr11852 is there a typical guideline to follow when determining the maximum number of hyperparameters, since you mentioned that 40 parameters seems like too many?

Comment: this might be interesting https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/gp_part3/part3.html